# Capybara not attaching file with input tag

Tags: html, capybara

I've tried attaching a file with different a option but its not working.

1) `attach_file('file-input', Rails.root + 'spec/files/books.jpg',:visible => false)`

> Error:  Unable to find file field "file-input"

If I use `page.has_css? ('.file-input')` its able to find CSS.

I tried using other locators also:

2) `attach_file('#library_resource_files', Rails.root + 'spec/files/books.jpg',:visible => false)`

> Error:  Unable to find file field "file-input"

Scenario: Clicks on Upload button  click_link 'Upload' which is working fine.
and pop up opens , where do I need to click on button to attach the file.

Here is the HTML:

```
<input multiple="multiple" accept="image/*,
     audio/*,
     video/*,
     application/x-shockwave-flash,
     application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie,
     application/pdf,
     application/msword,
     application/vnd.google-apps.*,
     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,
     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,
     application/octet-stream,
     text/plain"
 class="file-input" type="file"
 name="library_resource[files][]" id="library_resource_files">
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `attach_file` - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method - it matches elements based on there id, name, or associated labels text (it does not match on a class name or with a CSS selector string).  Therefore you would want something like

```
attach_file('library_resource_files', Rails.root + 'spec/files/books.jpg')
```

For styling reasons the actual file input is often not visible on the page,  If that is true for you then you may (depending on the driver being used) be able to do

```
attach_file('library_resource_files', Rails.root + 'spec/files/books.jpg', visible: false)
```

if that doesn't work then you will need to modify the inputs CSS using`execute_script` to make it visible before calling attach_file

Comment: Thank you Thomas for replying..I really appreciate. Please guide how to identify which input element is hidden. .In above mentioned html I m not able to identify. Please guide .Thanks again -

Comment: @Meg I don't know that it is hidden.  I said "is often not visible" - to know whether yours is or not open the page in a real browser and inspect the element, see if it takes up any space on the page or whether it is transparent (opacity: 0), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation@Thomas.I will try to figure out.